# Any way to repeat this process twice using a loop?

Tags: c#, loops

Is there any way to use a loop (for, while, do-while) to loop through the process below twice, but store the results of the second iteration through the loop in two new variables, and then create a second ComplexNumber object using those variable values from the second iteration?

```
Console.Write("Real part: ");
double realValue = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Complex part: ");
double complexValue = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

ComplexNumber firstComplex = new ComplexNumber(realValue, complexValue);
```

Comment: Where's the 'process below' ?

By the sounds of it, make a 2-element array, and iterate through it, and store the results of your calculation in the array at the index of your iteration count.

Comment: Yes, there is. Have you made an attempt? Where are you stuck?

Comment: This is an indecipherable question.  Please rewrite with complete sentences and thoughts.  Thanks. P

Comment: yes i have, I'm stuck at how to not overwrite those two double variables in the second iteration through the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, sort of.

You can use an array of doubles to gather the input, but then when you get to passing them in as parameters to the constructor, you'll need to access the indexes directly, to get them out. Try and write the code yourself and ask again if you're stuck.

Comment: ah, I got it, thanks for not posting code and instead pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 4):

Local scoping within the for loop keeps us from needing unique variables each time.

```
ComplexNumber[] complexNumbers = new ComplexNumber[2];

for (int i = 0; i < complexNumbers.Length; i++)
{
        Console.Write("Real part: ");
        double realValue = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Complex part: ");
        double complexValue = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        complexNumbers[i] = new ComplexNumber(realValue, complexValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to figure this out for myself, and just wanted some pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Well, sorry for helping then.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing this, but you can be sure I didn't just copy/paste, I learned for myself.

Comment: no no, I really appreciate it, I apologize if I came off rude.